# Passing only the id or the entire entity in request body Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, request

I'm trying to build a REST api in Spring Boot and I'm in a dilemma regarding the Request Body.
If an entity, ex. Doctor has a subentity let's say a specialization, should I pass only the id of the specialization or the entire entity.

First case

```
    {
    
    "contractId": 1,
    "user": {
        "firstname": "",
        "lastname": "",
        "email": "",
        "phoneNumber": "",
        "username": "",
        "password": "",
        "gender": "", 
    },
    "roleId": 1,
    "specializations": [
        {
            "id": 1
        }, 
        {
            "id": 2
        }
    ],
    "qualifications": [
        {
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

second case

```
 {
    
    "contractId": 1,
    "user": {
        "firstname": "",
        "lastname": "",
        "email": "",
        "phoneNumber": "",
        "username": "",
        "password": "",
        "gender": "", 
    },
    "roleId": 1,
    "specializations": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Specialization_1"
        }
    ],
    "qualifications": [
        {
            "id": 1, 
            "name": "Qualification_1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name: "Qualification_2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you know the Id before making this call and the id is always binded to certain specialization, then yes, only Id should be enough